# is there a way to set text in login box that can be edited

Tags: android

is there a way to set text in login box that can be edited this what I have when I change android:hint to android:text nothing shows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:gravity="center" android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@id/rl_authenticate_vpn" android:background="#de12161e" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerInParent="true">
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="20.0dip" app:cardCornerRadius="10.0dip">
            <RelativeLayout android:background="@color/white" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerInParent="true">
                <RelativeLayout android:id="@id/ll_expandable" android:background="@color/white" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <RelativeLayout android:id="@id/relative_title" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="60.0dip">
                        <TextView android:textSize="20.0sp" android:textColor="@color/black" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:id="@id/tv_movie_id" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="Connect3" android:lines="2" android:drawablePadding="7.0dip" android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:drawableStart="@drawable/parental_password_lock" android:fontFamily="@string/font_family_medium" android:layout_marginStart="25.0dip" android:layout_toStartOf="@id/iv_cancel" android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
                        <ImageView android:id="@id/iv_cancel" android:tag="15" android:focusable="true" android:visibility="visible" android:nextFocusDown="@id/bt_resume" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_marginEnd="20.0dip" android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_cancel" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                    <ImageView android:id="@id/iv_div" android:background="@color/black" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="2.0px" android:layout_below="@id/relative_title" />
                    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@id/iv_div">
                        <TextView android:textSize="20.0sp" android:textColor="@color/black" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:id="@id/et_description" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="45.0dip" android:layout_marginTop="10.0dip" android:layout_marginBottom="10.0dip" android:fontFamily="@string/font_family_regular" android:paddingStart="10.0dip" android:layout_marginStart="25.0dip" android:layout_marginEnd="25.0dip" />
                        <EditText android:textColorHint="@color/white" android:id="@id/tv_vpn_username" android:background="@drawable/selector_verify_password_fields" android:focusable="true" android:nextFocusDown="@id/tv_vpn_password" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="40.0dip" android:layout_marginBottom="10.0dip" android:hint="@string/username" android:layout_below="@id/et_description" android:fontFamily="@string/font_family_regular" android:textDirection="locale" android:paddingStart="10.0dip" android:layout_marginStart="30.0dip" android:layout_marginEnd="30.0dip" />
                        <EditText android:textColorHint="@color/white" android:id="@id/tv_vpn_password" android:background="@drawable/selector_verify_password_fields" android:focusable="true" android:nextFocusUp="@id/tv_vpn_username" android:nextFocusDown="@id/bt_save_and_connect" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="40.0dip" android:layout_marginTop="10.0dip" android:layout_marginBottom="10.0dip" android:hint="@string/password" android:layout_below="@id/tv_vpn_username" android:fontFamily="@string/font_family_regular" android:textDirection="locale" android:paddingStart="10.0dip" android:layout_marginStart="30.0dip" android:layout_marginEnd="30.0dip" />
                        <Button android:textSize="18.0sp" android:textColor="@color/white" android:id="@id/bt_save_and_connect" android:tag="1" android:background="@drawable/back_btn_effect" android:focusable="true" android:nextFocusUp="@id/tv_vpn_password" android:layout_width="200.0dip" android:layout_height="40.0dip" android:layout_marginTop="10.0dip" android:layout_marginBottom="20.0dip" android:text="@string/save_connect" android:layout_below="@id/tv_vpn_password" android:layout_marginStart="40.0dip" />
                        <Button android:textSize="18.0sp" android:textColor="@color/white" android:id="@id/bt_close" android:tag="2" android:background="@drawable/logout_btn_effect" android:focusable="true" android:nextFocusLeft="@id/bt_save_and_connect" android:nextFocusUp="@id/tv_vpn_password" android:layout_width="150.0dip" android:layout_height="40.0dip" android:layout_marginTop="10.0dip" android:layout_marginBottom="20.0dip" android:text="@string/close" android:layout_below="@id/tv_vpn_password" android:layout_marginEnd="40.0dip" android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change height to wrapcontent 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
and change hint to text

when I implement your way. I can see only one pixel of text when typing something

Comment: Thanks for tips but when I change hint to text it does not show text just a blank box? any ideas?